# How can I use cloudwatch metric for `Latency-based` routing policy in route53?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-route53

I am deploying applications in AWS multiple regions. There are a few lambdas sitting behind API gateway. And I'd like to use `route53` routing policy to route traffic to different regions.

The policy I'd like to use is `Latency-based` policy which means route53 routes traffic to resources based on its response time. I have read this doc https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy.html and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-values-latency.html.

It works a little different than my thought. What I am looking for is the use the latency based on the response time in my API gateway or ALB. But based on the doc, it seems that latency is based on DNS resolve name server. Is there a way for me to use the latency based on cloudwatch metric like `IntegrationLatency`?

Comment: `IntegrationLatency` is between API gateway and lambda (or other integration backend). Its not between R53 and API gateway.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. This is what I am looking for. How can I make route53 route policy to route based on `IntegrationLatency`?

Comment: You can't. The policies are set by AWS and you can't modify them. You could maybe look at other DNS resolver then R53.